# yii using/understanding the model correctly

Tags: php, yii

I am looking to pull data for related products correctly with the YII framework, as Im only learning this framework Im wondering have you advice on how I should go about this.

Ive taken over a project which uses YII, and it seems to have already some functionality in place, but I dont know how to utilize it.

Here is my current code...

In my Product model I have written this myself..

```
public function getRelatedProducts($id)
{
    $rawData=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM '.Product::model()->tableName().' as Product LEFT JOIN '.ProductRelated::model()->tableName().' as ProductRelated  ON ProductRelated.related_id=Product.id LEFT JOIN '.Images::model()->tableName().' as image ON Product.image_id=image.id  WHERE ProductRelated.product_id='.$id.' ')->queryAll();

    return $rawData;
}
```

and I get this data using...

```
$related_products = Product::GetRelatedProducts($model->id);
```

This works but is not using the YII framework.

I have noticed there is a model called ProductRelated (with not much in it).But I am not sure how to use it.

This obviously refers to a table I have in the database called `product_related`, which has 2 fields, `product_id` and `related_id`, where `related_id` represents the id of the product to which it was assigned(related to).

I would like to use this class as it was obviously written with this in mind. Right now Im just skipping over it.

```
class ProductRelated extends BaseProductRelated     {

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}


public static function LoadByProductIdRelatedId($intProductId , $intRelatedId)
{

    return ProductRelated::model()->findByAttributes(array('product_id'=>$intProductId,'related_id'=>$intRelatedId));


    }



 }
```

Having read up some more about YII I have rebuilt my query...

```
    public function getRelatedProducts($id)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->alias = 'Product';
    $criteria->join ='LEFT JOIN  '.ProductRelated::model()->tableName().' as ProductRelated ON ProductRelated.related_id=Product.id';
    $criteria->join .=' LEFT JOIN  '.Images::model()->tableName().' as image ON Product.image_id=image.id';     
    $criteria->condition = 'ProductRelated.product_id='.$id.'';
    $criteria->order = 'Product.id DESC';

    return $criteria;

}
```

However I am not sure what to do with that final bit of code and how to link it up with the model I have shown above.

Comment: You may want to add more information on ProductRelated model so that we can assist you. Fields/reason you want to relate your query with that model.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post, and added some more info before the ProductRelated model

Comment: It'd be useful to see the base model (`BaseProductRelated`) . . .

Answer (score 0):

there are many mistakes in your code. I don't think your predecessor known yii very well too.
There are included functionalities to get relations.

read about yii relational active records:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Best regards

Comment: I should probably clarify, I wrote the first query as well. But thanks, Ill take a look

Answer (score 0):

Yii model uses  the **ActiveRecord** pattern. You'll find that the [relations()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail) method of your model allows you to define relational data.

If your Product.relations() method is properly set, then the related products shall be 'magically' available.

NB : I guess the relatedProduct table is an association table for a n-n relationship between Product and... Product so you will use MANY_MANY. Take a look at the sample code at the end of the documentation of the relations() method.